# dimension of a irreducible representation

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let G be a group and A an abelian subgroup of G. I want to prove that for each irreducible representation $p$ we have that $dim(p)\leq [G:A]$.
I proved that for each subspace $p(A)-$invariant $W$, $W_0= \sum_{g \in G}p(g)(W)$ is a p(G)-invariant of V (hint of the professor) and that for a abelian finite group, each irreducible representation has dimension 1.
But how can i go on? I wish i can tell more of what i did in this question but i honestly have no idea how to proceed.I was thinking in the canonical decomposition of a representation, considering the subspaces W,but after some writing it seems non-sense.
Any help are welcome.
Ps:my representation theory course uses only knowlegde of theory of groups, not modules or other stuff.

Comment: Are you working in the “““easy””” case (finite groups, algebraically closed fields with chacteristics coprime with $|G|$), or are there subtleties?

Comment: The field needs to be algebraically closed, otherwise it's false. As $Z_3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ demonstrates. As for your question, do you really need all $g\in G$ in the definition of $W_0$? In other words, what is $\dim(W_0)$?

Comment: I assume that you are not familiar with induced representations and Frobenius reciprocity? Because the result follows very neatly from that.

Comment: forgot to mention, the field is C and the group is finite,

Comment: and no, i cant use induced representations for this, is literally the next content of the course

Answer (score 1):

You need some assumption on your group and the coefficient field.

I think the idea is to find a non-zero vector on which the abel group acts as a character. Then the remaining things work through: the representation is generated by the vector (as it is irreducible). As the abel subgroup acts on it as a character, we get a spanning set of the representation of order smaller than or equal to [G:H].

For example it is the case if your group is finite and the representation is taking coefficients in an algebraically closely field.